# Convert QList iterator to index

Tags: c++, qt

I use [qLowerBound](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qLowerBound-2) to find an item in a `QList`, but this function returns an iterator, while I need an index (I'll pass it to another function that expects an index). Is there a way to get the index from the `QList` iterator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can subtract iterator to beginning of your list from your iterator to get an index, since pointer arithmetic is defined on iterators:

```
int idx = iter-yourList.begin();
```

See [QList-iterator-reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist-iterator.html#operator--2)

Comment: alternatively, use std::distance().

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Frank Osterfeld's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354641/convert-qlist-iterator-to-index#comment33980321_22354764), you can use this:

```
const auto index = std::distance(yourList.begin(), currentIteratorOnYourList);
```

Checkout this [article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/10/26/how-to-access-the-index-of-the-current-element-in-a-modern-for-loop/) from Fluent{C++} blog.